# Open google chrome and change url with vbscript

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

I want to open chrome with a url. After 10 seconds, it needs to redirect to other url.

```
Dim iURL 
Dim iURL2
Dim objShell

iURL = "http://10.184.165.112/platform-gwt-war/"
iURL2 = "http://10.184.165.112/platform-gwt-war/#Plant_Equipment_Status"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "Chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
objShell.ShellExecute "Chrome.exe", iURL2, "", "", 2
```

This is opening 2 tabs.
Send keys is also not working.

any suggestions?